# Can i use a case statement to convert a varchar to decimal and use that in my where clause?

Tags: sql-server, select, decimal, where-clause, varchar

I have a column which I want to convert to decimal so I can then use it to compare in my `where` clause. I want to make sure all values from the column are greater or equal to 1.3. I converted the column successfully in the `select` statement but when attempting to do the same convert in the where clause I get the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(USER_3) = 1 
          THEN Convert(varchar(50), CONVERT(decimal(14,2), USER_3))
       END AS KG_M
FROM PART 
WHERE USER_3 IS NOT NULL 
      AND CASE 
           WHEN ISNUMERIC(USER_3) = 1
              THEN Convert(varchar(50), CONVERT(decimal(14,2), USER_3))
           END >= 1.3
```

Comment: you should use `>= '1.3'` since you are converting to `varchar`

Comment: Oh, wow such a small oversight... thank you. Sorry for the bogus question, i knew it should've been working. I didn't even think of syntax error.

Comment: Can you show the data present in `USER_3` column. `ISNUMERIC` is not reliable

Comment: The data is several thousand rows, but i know that all the data is indeed decimal values.

Comment: @Lamak - Why are converting the numeric value to `varchar` you will get wrong results.

Comment: No. you can't..  a single COLUMN can only have ONE data type.  You might be able to first limit in the where clause to only numeric values and then do your comparison and then union in those that the system sees as not numeric so long as you cast the numeric back to varchar on the union.

Comment: can you run `select * from part where not isNumeric(user_3)` and see if you get any results?  if so you may have a non-display character or value which can't be cast/converted to decimal.  and then try it with `not isNumeric(trim(user_3))`  The problem with varchar data is that it could have spaces, hard returns, or other non-display characters which LOOK like they could be converted to numeric but actually can't. One way around this would be to ensure the value are numeric by doing what @RossBush did in putting the isnumeric(user_3) = 1 in the where. however this may eliminate some data.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not? Here's a self-contained example:

```
select a.ID
     , b.KG_M
from (values
    (1, N'12345678')
  , (2, N'ABCDEFGH')
) as a (ID, USER_3)
cross apply (values(
    case IsNumeric(a.USER_3)
        when 1 then Convert(varchar(50), Convert(decimal(14, 2), a.USER_3))
        else a.USER_3
    end
)) as b (KG_M)
where b.KG_M >= '1.3';
```

We simply use the `APPLY` operator to contain our calculation for reuse later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose one way to convert. I would use the native type for comparison, decimal.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ID, KG_M=CAST(USER_3 AS decimal(14,2))  
    FROM PART 
    WHERE 
        ISNUMERIC(USER_3) = 1
)AS X
WHERE 
    X.KG_M >= 1.3
```

Allow strings that are not numbers in outoput

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
       ID, 
       USER_3_AsDecimal=CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(USER_3) THEN CAST(USER_3 AS decimal(14,2)) ELSE NULL END,
       USER_3  
    FROM PART 
    WHERE 
        NOT USER_3 IS NULL
)AS X
WHERE 
    X.USER_3_AsDecimal IS NULL 
    OR
    X.USER_3_AsDecimal >= 1.3
```

Comment: so lets say user_ID = 'TEST' it passes the null check fails the numeric check; and the output of the query will have a column called KG_M which has two datatypes.  I think SQL server will complain, wouldn't it?  Didn't think a result set could have two datatypes for one column.  Maybe it will implicitly cast decimal back to varchar;but I don't think so.

Comment: If your ISNUMERIC=1 is used in the where then you can ensure all string values are numeric and can safely be converted to a decimal.

Comment: that should/would do it.  However, it may (will based on the error) eliminate some data that they are after because of Garbage/unexpected data in the user_3 field.

Comment: The cast/convert will not complain if the value can be casted as the type. I think you were letting string values into the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a syntax error, the case in the where clause was a success the entire time.

"you should use >= '1.3' since you are converting to varchar" credit to @Lamak in comments